# Rails 4 Multiple file upload using carrierwave and nested forms

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, carrierwave, nested-forms

I have a catalog item with many images and trying to upload all of it by one request using nested forms and carrierwave. I also use responders, haml and simple form.
So, it's something like:

**item.rb**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end
```

**image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for(@item, :html => {:multipart => true }) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :description
    = f.input :price

  = simple_fields_for :images do |image|
    = image.file_field :image, multiple: true

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
...
def new
  @item = Item.new
  respond_with(@item)
end

def create
  @item = Item.new(item_params)
  @item.save
  respond_with(@item)
end
...
def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(
    :name, :description, :price,
    image_attributes: [:image]
  )
end
```

I'm new to rails and it's obviously not working the way i want it to. It saves item and completely ignore all images.

So, i'm wondering, is there any way to achieve my goal without constructions like

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(item_params)
  params[:images].each do |image|
    img = Image.new
    img.image = image
    @item.images << img
  end
  @item.save
  respond_with(@item)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, finally i found the answer. There was some mistakes in my html form.
The first mistake was pretty much obvious. I used

```
= simple_fields_for :images do |image|
```

instead of

```
= f.simple_fields_for :images do |image|
```

in **_form.html.haml**
The second one i found after reading this [article.](http://alagram.github.io/blog/2013/11/04/uploading-multiple-files-with-carrierwave-and-a-nested-form/)
So i changed my nested form to this:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :images, Image.new do |image_form|
    = image_form.file_field :image, multiple: true,
                   name: "item[images_attributes][][image]"
```

And as Pavan advised, used *images_attributes* in pluralized form in my **items_controller.rb**:

```
def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(
    :name, :description, :price,
    images_attributes: [:image]
  )
end
```

And thats all.

Comment: The extra `[]` in `name: "item[images_attributes][][image]"` was what tripped me up 

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `new` method to like below

```
def new
  @item = Item.new
  @item.images.build
  respond_with(@item)
end
```

Also, as you are uploading ***multiple images***, change your `item_params` to below

```
def item_params
  params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :price, images_attributes: [:image => []])
end
```

Comment: Nope, still the same result. Item saved, but images ignored.

Comment: Still doesn't work, but I discovered that **:item** and **:images** are two separate elements of the **param** hash, so couldn't it be something wrong with my nested form implementation?